# Error: The Cubes collection has been updated on the server

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, reportbuilder3.0

So, I'm going along in SSRS building a new report, as you do, and as I'm building the query from my SSAS cube I get the error: "The Cubes collection has been updated on the server."  I can't find anything on the interwebs that would fix my issue.  The odd thing is that I can build out the query for a while before getting this error, meaning I'm able to add 7-10 fields before the error presents itself.  After the error I can't save it because it can't verify that the query is working.  So I have to close it all down and restart building the query, but again, after a few fields get added I get the same error.

Yesterday we added a tabular instance to our BI server so we could convert our SSAS cubes to a tabular model and then utilize power bi and this seems to be when I started to see the issue.  I'm not sure if they're related.  I did restart the server last night hoping that would correct anything that went awry, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Cubes need processing.  Process your cubes and try again.